# Why couldn't Master Shifu contain Tai Lung and Po has to defeat him?

Tags: character, analysis, kung-fu-panda

Why couldn't Master Shifu contain Tai Lung, forcing Po to later defeat him in **Kung Fu Panda**?

Why is it that Master Shifu couldn't contain or defeat Tai Lung, but Po has to fight aganst Lung in order to save Shifu and the Valley of Peace?

It is showed that both Shifu and Po knew [Wuxi Finger Hold](http://kungfupanda.wikia.com/wiki/Wuxi_Finger_Hold). So why did Po have to defeat him? He is the student of Shifu anyways. Why is it that the teacher who knew Kung Fu so well, was ultimately unable to defeat Tai Lung? Lung was also a former student of Shifu.

**Why was Shifu unable to do what was necessary?**

Comment: Highly related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12405/what-is-the-wuxi-finger-hold-with-which-po-defeats-tai-lung-in-kung-fu-panda?rq=1

Comment: @Paulie_D It seems not that related. This one is more centered on Shifu, and why he didn't defeat Tai Lung himself. /while question you've mentioned focused on Wuxi finger hold and what happened to Tai Lung

Answer (score 8):

### Because he loved Tai Lung as he is his own

As shown in the flashback scene, it shows *Master Shifu* adopted infant *Tai Lung* when somebody left Lung at *Shifu's* door. *Shifu* adopted *Tai Lung*, fed him, teach him and it shows that *Shifu* really did care about *Tai Lung*. Either *Shifu* loved *Tai Lung* as his own.

*Shifu* loved *Tai Lung* so much that he was willing to give up the dragon scroll to him. But *Master Ooogway* saw darkness in *Tai Lung* and refuses. Enraged Lung became evil and *Oogway* had to defeat him, while *Shifu* watching shockingly.

Years later, it shows that *Shifu* still loves *Lung* deep inside.

So when *Lung* attacked him, *Shifu* only sees that little lovable kid version of *Lung* and *Shifu* was unable to fight with him as he can do. That's why *Po* has to fight *Lung* and defeat him.

No matter what he knew, *Shifu* couldn't hit the kid once he loved deep in his heart.